# What is the main difference of thread.join vs queue.join?

Tags: python, multithreading

In Python, what is the difference between using a `thread.join` vs a `queue.join`? I feel that it could both do the same job in some scenarios. Especially if there is a one-one correpodence between thread spawned and item picked from the queue for a job. Is it something like if you are going to use `Threading` on a `queue`, it is best to depend on `queue.join` and if you are just doing something in paralelly where there is no `queue` data structure used, but its something like a `list` you could use `thread.join`? Ofcourse in the scenario of `thread.join` you need to mention all the threads spawned.

Also just as an aside is `queue` something you would normally use for consuming input? I think in the scenario of chaining inputs for another job it makes sense to use as an output as well, but in general queue is for processing input? Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Queue.join` will wait for the queue to be empty (actually that `Queue.task_done` is called for each item after processing). `Thread.join` will block until all threads terminates. The behavior using one or other might be similar if all the threads take items from the queue, make a task and return when there's nothing left. However you can still have threads which don't use a queue at all, thus `Queue.join` would be useless.